# Modify data in php codeigniter active record result without changing structure

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object, activerecord

I've got a codeigniter active record query that uses get('table_name')->result();

The output is below, what i'd like to do is unserialize(base_64_decode) the "venue_opening_hours" string and replace that string in the data structure with the result of the unserialized & base64_decoded data. I know i can array_walk to do this normally, but i don't see how to access that particular bit of data as an object within an array...

Thanks!

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#142 (4) {
    ["entry_id"]=>
    string(2) "15"
    ["google-id"]=>
    string(40) "552e7c08d3b86c14d130ebe43a0ba421d03a60ae"
    ["venue_opening_hours"]=>
    string(148) "YToxOntzOjEzOiJvcGVuaW5nX2hvdXJzIjthOjE6e3M6NzoicGVyaW9kcyI7YToxOntzOjQ6Im9wZW4iO2E6Mjp7czozOiJkYXkiO3M6MToiNSI7czo0OiJ0aW1lIjtzOjQ6IjIzMTUiO319fX0="
    ["title"]=>
    string(18) "Place Name"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#143 (4) {
    ["entry_id"]=>
    string(2) "18"
    ["google-id"]=>
    string(40) "71d9c8e1f64f330637c96d30a0ae15533836a85e"
    ["venue_opening_hours"]=>
    string(972) "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"
    ["title"]=>
    string(24) "Other place name"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd access it using:

```
$array[0]->venue_opening_hours
```

in a for loop...

```
//foreach ($array as &$arrayItem)
//{
  foreach ($arrayItem as &$object)
  {
       // extract and convert it...
       //$openinghours =  unserialize(base64_decode($object->venue_opening_hours));
       // Update it...
       $object->venue_opening_hours = $unserialize(base64_decode($object->venue_opening_hours));
  }
//}
```

The `&$object` is a reference, so the assignment will change the value in the original result set...

Also I forgot to also loop the array ... I think! so added the outer loop :)

Comment: How would that work in a foreach loop where there were say 10 entries and needed to access each one and apply that function? Obviously i would not be able to know the array key index to do that?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Hmm, yes, but then that would be taking it out of the original structure, i need to modify that data but maintain that data structure as the next method that needs it needs it in a certain format.

Comment: Oh cool, that's impressive stuff, i for some odd reason didn't think to reference it. That was my main issue. Thanks a lot Brian, you've been amazing :)

Comment: Hmm, i'm getting an error saying:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object

this line of code is the issue:

$object->venue_opening_hours = unserialize(base64_decode($object->venue_opening_hours));

Comment: Right, fixed that, didn't need the outer loop. Cheers Brian! You rock!

Comment: No probs... I didn't think the it was needed!